# Preparing target test application's context for testing

Tags: android, robotium, android-testing

I have an Android app and a test project running some unit tests and automated UI tests, using Robotium. I want to make sure the target app's context is in a certain state before each test is started up. Normally, one would do this in the setUp() method of the test class.

That the target app's Application instance does some initialisation work based on some values in the shared pref store. I want to make sure these values are set as relevant to my test project's needs.

The problem is that the target Application instance's onCreate() method is executed before the setUp() method. Therefore, the values from the test's setUp() method are not taken into consideration. What would be the correct way to do this initialisation work?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to create a `FakeTestOnlyActivity` doing all init work in the `onCreate` before calling `super.onCreate()` :

```
public FakeTestOnlyActivity extends ActivityToTest {

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
          //do initialization
          ...
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this would not work. The Application's instance will be created before the activity is launched anyhow.